# Changing the value of a XLFORM row

Tags: swift, xlform

I am using the XLFORM library with swift, I want to clear the value of the row after a successfully request .

I am trying to get the row object using self.form.formRowWithTag and changing the value using .value but unfortunately I am not able to get the row's object :(

anyone can help on this ?

Answer (score 6):

I was searching for this answer as well, and your answer gave me inspiration.

What you have done so far is correct. Here is the code:

```
self.form.formRowWithTag("whatever-tag").value = nil
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

The key is to reload your `UITableView`

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 2):

While the above answer might work, I found out how to do it the way XLForm author wants you to do. On [XLForm Github](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm), the author says:

> You may have to update the cell to see the UI changes if the row is
>   already presented. `-(void)reloadFormRow:(XLFormRowDescriptor *)formRow`
>   method is provided by `XLFormViewController` to do so.

So, you can do this:

```
var row = self.form.formRowWithTag("whatever-tag")
row.value = nil
self.reloadFormRow(row)
```

Hope this helps.